# What dance is Araragi dancing?

Tags: monogatari-series

As Koyomi gets ready to make his sister a boiling hot bath in episode 1 of Tsukimonogatari, he does a little dance:

[image: Koyomi dancing]

It seems familiar - is it a reference to another series?

Comment: it could be some sort of signal sequence like the airplane signalers

Comment: Just out of curiosity, when does this scene happen? I don't remember it.

Comment: @Torisuda Roughly 10 minutes into episode 1 of Tsukimonogatari.

Comment: @senshin Ah, Tsukimonogatari! I didn't even realize it was out. I can't believe I let a Monogatari release sneak up behind me like that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this is just supposed to be Tsukihi's schtick from her OP in Nisemonogatari (Platinum Disco).

[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]